# HTML5 video implimentation will not work in ipad

Tags: html

HTML5 video implimentation is not working in ipad by the following code.

```
<video width="100%" height="340" id="player1" controls preload="none"  poster="../media/echo-hereweare.jpg" autoplay>

    <source src="video/1x1trial444.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
    <source type="video/webm" src="video/1x1trial444.webm" />
    <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
    <source type="video/ogg" src="video/1x1trial444.ogg" />         

</video>
```

Comment: Have you done some debugging to find any error?

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious: Are the paths correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the codec info on the source and make sure your mp4 is encoded with the baseline level 3 (seems to be the safer choice for older devices)

```
<source src="video/1x1trial444.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source src="video/1x1trial444.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
```